# Invalid use of incomplete type with with 2 related classes

Tags: c++, oop, compilation

My code has 2 related classes:
`Class1` has pointer field to instance of `Class2`;
`Class2` has pointer field to instance of `Class1`:

**class1.hpp**

```
#ifndef __CLASS_1_HPP
#define __CLASS_1_HPP

#include "all.hpp"

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
private:
    Class2 *c2;
};

Class1::Class1() 
{
    c2 = new Class2();
}

#endif // __CLASS_1_HPP
```

**class2.hpp**

```
#ifndef __CLASS_2_HPP
#define __CLASS_2_HPP

#include "all.hpp"

class Class2
{
public:
    Class2();
private:
    Class1 *c1;
};

Class2::Class2() 
{
    c1 = new Class1();
}

#endif // __CLASS_2_HPP
```

**all.hpp**

```
#ifndef __ALL_HPP
#define __ALL_HPP

class Class1;
class Class2;
#include "class1.hpp"
#include "class2.hpp"

#endif // __ALL_HPP
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "all.hpp"
int main() {}
```

When I'm trying to compile this I get **Invalid use of incomplete type Class2** on line `c2 = new Class2();`. Division .hpp files on .hpp and .cpp does not help!

Comment: Note that names like `__CLASS_1_HPP` are not allowed to be created in user code - simply use `CLASS_1_HPP`

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'll keep this in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let see all these through the compiler glasses. After the pre-processor did it work you end up with a so called *translation unit* looking like this:

*main.cpp:*

```
class Class1;
class Class2;

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
private:
    Class2 *c2;
};

Class1::Class1() 
{
    c2 = new Class2();    // error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Class2'
    /// So all what the compiler knows at this point
    /// about Class2 is that's a class, but not how to create it.
    /// It was just declared but not defined yet.
}

class Class2
{
public:
    Class2();
private:
    Class1 *c1;
};

Class2::Class2() 
{
    c1 = new Class1();
}

int main() {}
```

At the line `c2 = new Class2();` all what the compiler knows about Class2 is that is's a *class*, but not how to create it. It was just declared but not defined yet.

So usually this problem is solved by putting the class member function definitions in separate source (e.g. cpp) files that include the header files with the definition of both classes.

*Class1.cpp:*

```
#include "class1.hpp"
#include "class2.hpp"
Class1::Class1() 
{
    c2 = new Class2();
}
```

*Class2.cpp:*

```
#include "class2.hpp"
#include "class1.hpp"
Class2::Class2() 
{
    c1 = new Class1();
}
```

And leave only the class defintions in the header files:

```
#ifndef __CLASS_1_HPP
#define __CLASS_1_HPP

class Class2;

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
private:
    Class2 *c2;
};
#endif // __CLASS_1_HPP
```

Answer (score 0):

`all.hpp` is included. So, `Class1` and `Class2` are forwarded until a full definition.

Then `class1.hpp`is included. The constructor for `Class1` is both declared and defined.

The definition of this ctor calls `new Class2()`, but at this point the constructor of `Class2` is not defined yet. The compiler only knows that Class1 stores a pointer to an object of type Class2, not how to build that object.

Perhaps you want to separate declarations (in headers) from definitions (in .cpp code)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you cramped:

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
private:
    Class2 * c2;
};
Class1::Class1()
{
    c2 = new Class2();
}
```

into the Class1.hpp
What you need to do is:

## Class1.hpp

```
#include all.hpp
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
private:
    Class2 * c2;
};
```

and

## Class1.cpp

```
#include "Class1.hpp"     
Class1::Class1()
{
    c2 = new Class2();
}
```

Same with the Class2.cpp/Class2.hpp
In your code you are not calling the constructors of c1 and c2 ( `Class1::Class1()` ), since you didn't create the objects there but in the hpp which doesn't work. If you want to create the objects in the header you can try initializers.